# Difference between environment etc. in testthat::test_check vs testthat::test_dir

Tags: r, testthat

This is somewhat deep R testing question, and as such, I'm not sure if general Stack Overflow is the right place for it, or if there's an R specific forum that would be better. 
Any pointers on that are welcome.

The scenario is: I have package that is using `testthat` and has some tests in `tests/testthat` and (for reasons that are important but, to be honest, I don't totally understand) there are some other tests in `inst/validation` that need to be run as well, as part of a validation script (i.e. the script that this post is about).

I was running `test_check(pkg)` in my `tests` folder and it was working fine, but I wasn't getting the extra tests (which makes sense). So then I switched to the following:

```
test_dirs <- c("tests/testthat", "inst/validation")
for (.t in test_dirs) {
  test_dir(.t)
}
```

Now a bunch of my tests are failing because they can't find some of the constants, etc. that are part of my package! (see note at the bottom for more details...)

So I dig in to the source code and find that `test_check()` actually calls `testthat:::test_package_dir` under the hood. Note the `:::` this is an *unexported* function, so I don't really just want to call it in my own code.

`testthat:::test_package_dir` in turn calls the following, before calling `test_dir()` itself:

```
  env <- test_pkg_env(package)
  withr::local_options(list(topLevelEnvironment = env))

  withr::local_envvar(list(
    TESTTHAT_PKG = package,
    TESTTHAT_DIR = maybe_root_dir(test_path)
  ))

  test_dir(...
```

Sooooo... it seems like `test_check()` essentially just does some things to load the package environment (note `test_pkg_env` is also *unexported*) and then calls `test_dir()`.

So I guess my question is: why? I've actually noticed this before with `test_file()` not working because it doesn't have everything in the package environment. Why do these functions *not* load the package environment like the other testing functions do?

Or really, my question is: is there a way to make them load it? And specifically in my case, is there a way to do what I'm trying to do (run tests in a few different directories) *and* have it load the package environment?

I notice this in the `test_dirs` docs:

```
env -- Environment in which to execute the tests. Expert use only.
```

which is set to `test_env()` by default. I have a feeling this is my answer, but I can't figure out how to get the package environment without basically copy/pasting a bunch of code out of functions that are hidden in `:::`. Perhaps I don't qualify as an "expert"...

Thanks for any insight and/or solutions!

*note at the bottom:*
Specifically my issue is that I have some "constants" in my `aaa.R` that are mostly just hard-coded strings or lists like:

```
SUMMARY_NAME <- "summary"
SUMMARY_COUNT <- "sum_count"
SUMMARY_PATH <- "sum_path"

SUM_REQ_COLS <- list(
  list(name = SUMMARY_NAME, type = "character"),
  list(name = SUMMARY_COUNT, type = "numeric"),
  list(name = SUMMARY_PATH, type = "character"),
)
```

These are things that I use for checking S3 classes and other purposes so that I don't have hard-coded strings all over my code. The point is: I use some of these in my tests, which works fine for `test_check()` and `devtools::check()` and `devtools::test()` but dies when I try to use `test_dir()` or `test_file()` because they can't be found, presumably because the package environment isn't loaded.

Comment: Did you try build / load all under RStudio to load all package dependencies / constants?

Comment: yes, it works when I do `load_all` because that pulls everything in. Buuuut... maybe I'm off base, but that feels hacky to do in the code. Like, I feel sure that's _not_ what is happening in test_check under the hood. But maybe they're equivalent? I'm not sure.

Comment: now I'm rethinking this. Is @Waldi right? I was calling `require(pkg)` (and then my hacky "build the environment code") before I ran the tests, but if I just do `devtools::load_all(".")` it all works! Is there a downside to this? I'm not sure.

Comment: If it works, I see no down side as load all is supposed to simulate what happens when the package is installed and loaded